# contract works in remix but not when deployed in ropsten test network

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-debugging, ropsten, rinkeby

The contract is present at [issue with var keyword in solidity. what to use instead of var keyword?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48755/issue-with-var-keyword-in-solidity-what-to-use-instead-of-var-keyword/48757#48757)

It works in remix. Using remix i deployed the contract into ropsten test network but when i try to validate the contract i don't get the expected output.

first i will add user and then view the user to see how many does he have.
Add user:
[image: Add User]

View user:
[image: View user Input]

View user output:
[image]

In ropsten some times i am not able to deploy due to high gas. some time i don't get the same view user output as i get in remix. Can some one guide me on how to overcome in deploying this smart contract in test environment and get the same output as i get in remix?

Also tried in rinkeby but not able to get the output as in remix? anything wrong with my contract. Below the is output what i get in rinkeby test network.
[image: Rinkeby viewuser output]

if it is not clear any where kindly let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did this later work?

Answer (score 4):

Ropsten has some problems:

- **A PoW testnet is so hard to maintain because you spend a lot of electricity and GPU/CPU to mine receiving fake ether** which has no value.
- Because of point 1 problem, **there aren't a lot of miners on the testnet that behave correctly**, and several attacks had successed on it because **archieve the 51% of the computation power of the testnet is not that hard**. Here you have
  an article to read about some of them:
  https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/71dojd/ropsten_is_currently_under_attack/
- **That's why other testnets with PoA or PoS appeared** to let developers **test their smartcontracts safely and without problems**.

So my recomendation is: **Test the contract on another testnet like Rinkeby (PoS) or Kovan (PoA)** and you'll be sure that the problem is in your deployment and not a testnet problem.

Don't wotty about **the contract functionallity, it'll be the same**, the only different thing is that the **transactions will go faster than in Ropsten due to the proof algorithm is different.**

Here you have some info about PoS and PoA if you're interested to know about it:

https://bitfalls.com/2018/02/08/what-is-an-ethereum-testnet-and-how-is-it-used/

There's also links to it's faucets to get some fake ether to test your contracts.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried the same in rinkeby test network still facing the same issue. can some one guide if my contract is wrong ? or related to something else.

Comment: Can you post the code of the contract?

Comment: Hello CPereez the code is the present at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48755/issue-with-var-keyword-in-solidity-what-to-use-instead-of-var-keyword/48757#48757 . Kindly let me know if you have any queries.