# issue with var keyword in solidity. what to use instead of var keyword?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

When i try to run the below code in remix it works fine but as var keyword is deprecated so i tried to used an alternative way to fix the warning but it resulted in wrong output.

I was trying to achieve:

1) to add a user

namestring - some random name like random

linkstring - some random link like "https://www.google.com"

docConventionstring - some random convention like random1docconvention1

on moving the user will have 10 points in struct. If again i move the same user into struct it will update the totalpoints to 20. Here the issue is var keyword is depricated and when i use this same contract in truffle it is not returning the output as expected.

```
function AddUser(string namestring,string linkstring,string docConventionstring) public{                          
    bytes32 name=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(namestring));
    bytes32 link=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(linkstring));
    bytes32 docConvention=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(docConventionstring));
    uint32 existingTotalPoints=userTotalPoints(name);
     var user=bytesMappingToken[name];
    user.orginalName=name;
    user.originalKshoplink=link;
    user.validated=false;
    user.Points=firstTimeUserPoints;
    user.totalPoints=existingTotalPoints+firstTimeUserPoints;
    updateUserTotalPoints(name,user.totalPoints);
    user.orginalDocumentConvention=docConvention;
    struUsers.push(user);             
}
```

2) so I tried to change the add user function like below without using var:

```
function AddUser(string namestring,string linkstring,string docConventionstring) public{                
    bytes32 name=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(namestring));
    bytes32 link=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(linkstring));
    bytes32 docConvention=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(docConventionstring));
    uint32 existingTotalPoints=userTotalPoints(name);
    uint32 totalPoints=existingTotalPoints+firstTimeUserPoints;
    struUsers.push(struUser(name,link,docConvention, false,firstTimeUserPoints,totalPoints));
}
```

When i use the above add user function i don't the output as i expect. Below is the whole contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;
contract sample{
address owner=0x1234;    
uint32 firstTimeUserPoints=10;
struct struUser{
    bytes32 orginalName;
    bytes32 originalKshoplink;
    bytes32 orginalDocumentConvention;
    bool validated;
    uint32 Points;
    uint32 totalPoints;
}
struct struUserTotalPoints{
    bytes32 orginalName;
    uint32 totalPoints;
}
//mapping(string=>struUser)MappingToken;
mapping(bytes32=>struUser)bytesMappingToken;
struUser[] struUsers;
struUserTotalPoints[] struArrayUserTotalPoints;
string[] docConventionMappers;
string[] orginalName;
event printAddUserSuccess(string message);
event viewUser(string username, uint32 totalpoints);

modifier isOwner() {
    // if a condition is not met then throw an exception
    require (msg.sender == owner) ;
    _;
}

//TO INSERT A RECORD WITH SOME DATA

function AddUser(string namestring,string linkstring,string docConventionstring) public{

    /*
    bytes32 name=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(namestring));
    bytes32 link=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(linkstring));
    bytes32 docConvention=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(docConventionstring));
    uint32 existingTotalPoints=userTotalPoints(name);
    uint32 totalPoints=existingTotalPoints+firstTimeUserPoints;
    struUsers.push(struUser(name,link,docConvention, false,firstTimeUserPoints,totalPoints));
    */


    bytes32 name=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(namestring));
    bytes32 link=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(linkstring));
    bytes32 docConvention=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(docConventionstring));
    uint32 existingTotalPoints=userTotalPoints(name);
     var user=bytesMappingToken[name];
    user.orginalName=name;
    user.originalKshoplink=link;
    user.validated=false;
    user.Points=firstTimeUserPoints;
    user.totalPoints=existingTotalPoints+firstTimeUserPoints;
    updateUserTotalPoints(name,user.totalPoints);
    user.orginalDocumentConvention=docConvention;
    struUsers.push(user);
    //docConventionMappers.push(docConvention);

    //struUsers.push(struUser({orginalName:name,originalKshoplink:link, 
    //validated:user.validated,Points:user.Points,totalPoints:user.totalPoints,
    //orginalDocumentConvention:docConvention}));

    //struUser memory user=struUser(name,link,docConvention, false,firstTimeUserPoints,totalPoints);

    //struUsers.push(struUser);
    emit printAddUserSuccess("user added successfully!");

}


 function userTotalPoints(bytes32 name) public returns(uint32){  //FOR FETCHING TOTAL POINTS OF A USER

     bool isUserTotalPointsCalculated=false;

        for(uint j=0;j<struArrayUserTotalPoints.length;j++){
            //if(keccak256(struArrayUserTotalPoints[j].orginalName)==keccak256(name)){                    
            if(comparebytes(struArrayUserTotalPoints[j].orginalName,name)){
                isUserTotalPointsCalculated=true;
                return struArrayUserTotalPoints[j].totalPoints;
            }
        }
        if(!isUserTotalPointsCalculated){
            struArrayUserTotalPoints.push(struUserTotalPoints({orginalName:name,totalPoints:firstTimeUserPoints}));
            return 0;                
        }  
}

function userexists(string namestring) view public returns(uint32){
    bytes32 name=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(namestring));
     for(uint j=0;j<struArrayUserTotalPoints.length;j++){
            if(comparebytes(struArrayUserTotalPoints[j].orginalName,name)){
               return bytesMappingToken[name].Points;
            }
        }
        return 5;
}

   function comparebytes (bytes32 a, bytes32 b) pure public returns (bool){
   //return keccak256(a) == keccak256(b);
   return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a))==keccak256(abi.encodePacked(b));
   }


function viewuser(string name)public returns(string,uint32,uint32){ //
    bytes32 bytesname=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(name));
    uint32 totalpoints=userTotalPoints(bytesname);
    return (name,bytesMappingToken[bytesname].Points,totalpoints);
}

function updateUserTotalPoints(bytes32 name,uint32 totalPoints) public{
    for(uint j=0;j<struArrayUserTotalPoints.length;j++){
            if(comparebytes(struArrayUserTotalPoints[j].orginalName,name)){
                struArrayUserTotalPoints[j].totalPoints=totalPoints;
            }
        }
}


function () public payable {

}
}
```

How should i remove var keyword and use the alternative solution to get the expected output. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this:

```
var user=bytesMappingToken[name];
```

The fix is to use an explicit type. In this case, the type is `struUser`:

```
struUser user=bytesMappingToken[name];
```

**EDIT**

Per comments below, using the explicit `storage` keyword will silence the warning:

```
struUser storage user = bytesMappingToken[name];
```

Comment: Thank you Smarx! I tried it earlier but it says to use storage keyword to silence the warning. I am newbie to this could you let me know how to silence the warning. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: How about this? `struUser storage user=bytesMappingToken[name];`

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'll edit my answer to include that.